# Not able to write string repeatedly over the serial

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port

On a Ubuntu-Focal PC, I am writing a character string over the USB to another device (Arduino-Due in my case).
The string I am sending is received well on the other side, but I can’t write a second time.
The reason is that my program hangs itself up in the first write and doesn’t get out of it. It sends the 1st string well but somehow gets hung up in it.
Most port settings that one can change, refer to receiving data, but I am only sending, so I really don’t know why my write() gets caught up.
My code is rather standard:

```
// * * * * * * Serial functions * * * * * 

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
                return -1;
        }

        cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
        cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

        tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
        // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
        // as \000 chars
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
        tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                        // no canonical processing
        tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 20;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

        tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                        // enable reading
        tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
        tty.c_cflag |= parity;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
}//end set_interface_attribs()


void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
                return;
        }

        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
                printf("error %d setting term attributes", errno);
}//end set_blocking()


 
// * * * * *  Main * * * * * * * * * *


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  
  printf("entering main \n");
  
 
  char *portname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
  //std::string portname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
 
  int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
  if (fd < 0)
  {
        printf("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
        return 0;
  }

  set_interface_attribs (fd, 9600, 0);  // set speed to 9600 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
  set_blocking (fd, 0);                // set no blocking
 
  
  while(true)
  { 
    printf("entering write() \n");
    
    int n = write(fd, "#MCM;-061.456;976543.2@", 23);  // sends well 1st time but gets hung up    
    if(n<=0) 
    {
        cout << n << "write error \n";
        return 0;
    } 
    usleep ((7 + 25) * 100);             // sleep enough to transmit the 7 plus
                                     
    sleep(1000); //just for testing    

  }//end while()
   
   return 0;

}//end main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The sleep(1000) does 1000 seconds and not 1000 ms as I thought. Furthermore, I added 2 characters to the string: '\r' and '\n' and consequently I increased the 23 to 25. Works fine now.